# tomcat request forward forbidden

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to access a csv-file in a webapp (conterra mapapps 4.5.0) and i get the following error in the webapp-specific log:

> [WARN ] 2019-02-21T10:01:32,897 [http-nio-8080-exec-14]
>   de.conterra.mapapps.proxy.ProxyForward - Request Forward to url 
>   'file:///C:/Users/MapApps2/Downloads/TestProjects.csv' forbidden!

This error occurs no matter if the file is actually there or not.
So my question is if there is a simple way to test that tomcat can access a specific file or not? 
Is there a way like a tiny webapp that tests it?

Info: Everything is running on the same machine (tomcat and browser) and everything under the same user MapApps2. The machine is running on Windows 10.

**Edit**: The Solution was putting the file there:

> .../tomcat/webapps/ROOT

and access it via

> localhost:8080/TestProjects.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it is more about the location of the file, is your C:/Users/MapApps2/Downloads/ served by tomcat or not? 
If you put the csv file in the web root of tomcat probably you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where the CSV file is. If it's in the public web folder, then use

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/filename.csv");
```

Or if it's in the classpath, then use

```
InputStream input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.csv");
```